# Can't install anything using Pycharm because pipe doesn't have pip-egg-info(19.0.2)

Tags: python, pip, installation

It only shows error: "Files/directories not found in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\sfml\pip-egg-info"

I've tried almost all solution from here and still doesn't work.

Comment: Please give a full description what you have tried and what happened including the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda of a common issue, here's simple solution I used that doesn't require compiling it yourself:

1. download xgboost whl file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (make sure to match your
   python version and system architecture, e.g.
   "xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" for python 3.5 on 64-bit
   machine)
2. open command prompt
3. cd to your Downloads folder (or wherever you saved the whl file)
4. `pip install xgboost-0.6-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl` (or whatever your whl file is named)

if it requires privileged access to files, run the commands via a root session terminal, also if there was some missing dependencies download'em then retry

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work and I want to install sfml in Pycharm from Pycharm library, in cmd anyway doesn't work too.

Comment: in that case, you need to provide much more details

Comment: so let's start: 
I have JetBrains Pycharm, from there i can install "inside it" python librares for each project i create, there is by default installed pip version 19.0.2 and setuptools 40.8.0, some of librares i can install and some can't